# CB v Amateur Radio

Tags: jargon, citizens-band, q-codes

I am learning about Amateur Radio so as I can go for my foundation licence but I was on CB back in the days, a channel nine monitor and used the 10 code and the  Q code but all I can see is the 73 without any corresponding codes that follow 73 at the end of transmission so am wondering is the 73 just a code to distance Hams from CBers like the American Western Union 92 codes, can someone please tell me is there any other 73 codes other than end of transmission or not as I am ragging my brains out hitting brick walls for answers, 10-10. I just hope my question is not beneath some because I and still a CBer and always will be but I also want to engage with Ham operators once legal to do so, are there some decent Hams out there willing to help a fellow radio enthusiast or am I boot slops beneath you....I will wait and see.....

Comment: Hello Andrew, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q codes are mostly used with morse code to shorten common phrases, and some people discourage their use in phone modes, even in amateur radio.  (Other people think they are cool and continue to use them.)  A list of Q codes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_code#Q-codes_as_adapted_for_use_in_amateur_radio)

In communication classes I have taken, the 10 codes are generally discouraged, not because they come from CB, but because their meanings were never standardized, and there are variations in 10 code meanings from region to region.  It doesn't help that some police departments still use 10 codes, and they have added new ones that vary from department to department.

Amateur radio, especially when used for emergency operations, strives for clear communication.  10 codes by design try to obscure communication.

Comment: Thank you it confused me why I have heard many users give far from polite comments concerning CBers and what I have read so far in some books is full of miss information which is a shame really about CBers don't care how it works as long as it works and were limited to 5 mile radius when stuck on FM as we were even on normal atmospherics I was speaking to people all over Essex and Kent on various networks and when we bounced on what was known as freak atmospherics I managed Istanbul so this did look like a negative attitude to me glad to hear differently

Comment: You'll find that Ham communication is highly standardized in terms of station identification and codes.  Some of that is actually regulated (station identification, for example).  Citizen's Band tends to be a bit looser, even though the station ID rules are the same.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above. There are no "73 codes" like 10-codes, 73 is just 73. Yes, I know about the 92 code, but it's well and truly dead, with no survivors other than 73 and occasionally 88, so realistically speaking they stand on their own.

And 73 doesn't mean "end of transmission", it means "best wishes" or "warm regards" or just "have a great day!". All sentiments that tend to go *along* with a sign-off, just like you would use them to close a letter, but they don't mean the signoff itself — that would be "QRT" or "SK" or "clear" or "I'm hanging up the mic now, see you down the log".

That's why you'll see 73 on a QSL card or in an email: closing an email with "QRT" would be nerding out too much for most people's tastes, but closing an email with 73 is just being friendly.

And yes, of course there's a bit of group-recognition in it, but you're looking at it from an entirely unproductive viewpoint. Celebrating something shared doesn't have to be about denigrating anyone else. It's just one of the fundamental things that human beings do.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of that, it will save what little hair I have left so until such time as I pass my foundation and begin being able to chat on line instead of just listening I will sign off saying 10 - 10 and hope to be able to chat one day